# DB2 Query : insert data in history table if not exists already

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have History table and transaction table.....and reference table...
If status in reference table is CLOSE then take those record verify in History table if not there insert from transaction table..... wiring query like this .... checking better one... please advice.. this query can be used for huge data ?

```
 INSERT INTO LIB1.HIST_TBL               
( SELECT R.ACCT, R.STATUS, R.DATE FROM  
LIB2.HIST_TBL R JOIN LIB1.REF_TBL C     
ON R.ACCT = C.ACCT WHERE C.STATUS = '5' 
AND R.ACCT NOT IN                       
(SELECT ACTNO FROM LIB1.HIST_TBL)) ;
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you want. This part `b.*  from HIST_TBL b  join` and this part `b.ACTNO not in (select ACTNO from HIST_TBL   )` seem mutually exclusive. How can you get all `b.*` columns from a row that doesn't exist?

Comment: here is detail... it's example and assume HIST_TBL has only 3 fields

INSERT INTO LIB1.HIST_TBL H                                         
( SELECT R.ACCT, R.STATUS, R.DATE FROM LIB2.HIST_TBL R              
JOIN LIB1.NCBTORDR C ON T.ACCT = C.ACCT WHERE                       
C.STATUS = '5' AND R.ACTNO NOT IN (SELECT ACTNO FROM LIB1.NCBTADDR))

Comment: You reference columns `R.ACCT`, `T.ACCT` and `R.ACTNO` and correlatives H, R and C. Can you clean that up so the names and correlatives all match correctly? Otherwise it's not clear what you actually intend. But it seems plausible that it's close.

Comment: INSERT INTO LIB1.HIST_TBL               
( SELECT R.ACCT, R.STATUS, R.DATE FROM  
LIB2.HIST_TBL R JOIN LIB1.REF_TBL C     
ON R.ACCT = C.ACCT WHERE C.STATUS = '5' 
AND R.ACCT NOT IN                       
(SELECT ACTNO FROM LIB1.HIST_TBL))

Comment: That looks much better. You now have a statement like `INSERT INTO ... (SELECT ...)`. If you run only the `SELECT ...` in STRSQL or in iNav, does it show the exact rows you want?

Comment: Yes, it is showing all required records....

Comment: Then that is the statement you want to use in the INSERT. That should be all you need.

Comment: So my question is.... that query which i wrote will take much time if data is in huge volume? can we write in another way to get good performance?

Comment: Now you're asking a different question. You need to create a new question, include the INSERT statement that you want to run, give a description of tables including row counts, and ask about performance.

Comment: If you look it my query notes...i am asking  "wiring query like this .... checking better one... please advice.. this query can be used for huge data ?"

Comment: Well, yes, it can be used for any data volume so it can be used for "huge data". But you now have a query that "works"; whether it's appropriate requires a lot more info about your **specific** environment. A bunch of things might or might not be possible to improve it. An answer without you giving details of actual table and column definitions, indexes, table sizes, system resources, performance expectations (throughput? system impact? other?) and perhaps other details isn't possible without giving a course in database performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a current release of DB2 for i, take a look at the MERGE statement

```
MERGE INTO hist_tbl H
 USING (SELECT * FROM ref_tbl R
        WHERE r.status = 'S')
 ON h.actno = r.actno
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (actno,histcol2, histcol3) VALUES (r.actno,r.refcol2,r.refcol3)
 --if needed
 WHEN MATCHED
   UPDATE SET (actno,histcol2, histcol3) = (r.actno,r.refcol2,r.refcol3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.... I am on v7R1 and there are two more condition....... (1) Hist_tbl is same but in different lib  (2) i have many fields can't give filed names....

   Insert into LIB1.HIST_TBL (
    select b.*  from LIB2.HIST_TBL b  join      
   REF_TBL  c   on b.ACTNO =c.ACTNO           
   where c.status= '5'    and   b.ACTNO not in 
   (select ACTNO from LIB1.HIST_TBL   ) ) ;

Comment: You really should never use * in production code.  There's plenty of ways to get a list of the current fields and copy the list into your code.   When using *, you're creating a dependency between the table format and your code.  Might as well be using RPG.  That being said, if you want to do it, the syntax is `INSERT VALUES(...)`  The two conditions you had in the original post are handled by the MERGE I posted.  `NOT MATCHED` handles the `ACTNO not in (select ACTNO from LIB1.HIST_TBL ) `

Comment: I have two different libraries for HIST_TBL

Comment: So you're inserting records into LIB2.HIST_TBL that don't exist in LIB1.HIST_TBL?  What happens if they already exist in LIB1?

Comment: I am inserting record in LIB1.HIST_TBL from LIB1.HIST_TBL that don't exist in LIB1.HIST_TBL and has status '5' from ref_tbl. 
Actually same file but two diff environments...

Comment: Example 


INSERT INTO LIB1.HIST_TBL H                                         
( SELECT R.ACCT, R.STATUS, R.DATE FROM LIB2.HIST_TBL R              
JOIN LIB1.NCBTORDR C ON T.ACCT = C.ACCT WHERE                       
C.STATUS = '5' AND R.ACTNO NOT IN (SELECT ACTNO FROM LIB1.NCBTADDR))

Comment: So what's wrong with the above?  The only issue I see is that it's possible that the record is already in LIB1.HIST_TBL.  In which case, you could just use `MERGE` as in my original answer.

Comment: in your query, data is coming from REF table, but REF tables is just to check status....
we need to pull data from LIB2.HIST_TBL if status in REF as '5' ......... and check LIB1.HIST_TBL if not exists insert.

I have modifies my original query... because i have huge data worried about performance....